# Proxy error: Could not proxy request from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:44381/ (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, single-page-application

I am developing a Single Page Application (SPA) with ReactJS and ASP.NET. I I am trying to execute an HTTP Request to an endpoint from client side code. I used the default ASP.NET SPA template and changed my configuration as shown below.

```
            fetch(`/items/${id}`).then((response: any) => {
                return response.data;
            })
```

I modified the default web api template and use a Proxy Server in development instead. Like so:

```
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
             {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "Client";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://127.0.0.1:3000/");
                    //spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

When I execute the fetch in React client code, I get this error: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /items/1 from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:44381/ (ECONNREFUSED).`

How do I configure my server-side code to proxy the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the linked issue on GitHub, the `spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer` should already setup the proxy server itself as of .Net Core 3.1. So you might not need to be calling the `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` yourself manually.

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12008#issuecomment-573453266